# Node.js streams and responsibility for retrieval of new data

Tags: javascript, stream

Streams enable us to model infinite time-series'.

They can be implemented using generators, with values retrieved from the stream as the program wants via `next`.

But Node.js streams are event emitters and tell the program when to handle data through the `data` event.

This seems like responsibility for telling the program when to process new data is handed to the stream instead of leaving it with the program that presumably knows best whether it can handle the new data.

Is there a name for these two types of approaches (push and pull?) and when you each be used?

Answer (score 0):

However there is a push/pull method set available for streams (usually called streams2) I agree it's still quite complicated to use and generators were raised many times as a possible solution.

I implemented this in my [Scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) framework, so a very simple stream generator would look like this:

```
const dat = [1,2,3,4];
const iter = (function* () { yield* dat; })();
exports.stream = () => DataStream.fromIterator(iter);
```

You can run a test case using nodeunit in the [scramjet repo here](https://github.com/signicode/scramjet/blob/v4.2.2/samples/data-stream-fromiterator.js).